# How to consume from queues with custom names (defined on a fly) with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, php-amqplib, php-amqp

I have tasks with an ids, and each task has some amount of jobs to do:

- every job for each user;
- for each task, number of users and jobs are different.

And I want to put all the jobs to one queue with name task{id}, so I can control when the task is done (by empty queue task{id}), and automatically delete it with rabbitMQ help, and control a number of consumers working on one task{id}.

And I want my consumers works all the time like daemons and choose the queues with jobs automatically to work with.

The main question here is how to get name of a task inside a consumers to bind them to it?
Or maybe there can be some another trick with rabbitMQ to do so, without knowing name of a queue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Event Exchange Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/event-exchange.html) , this plugin allows you to consumes internal events and re-publishes them to a topic exchange, thus exposing the events to clients (applications).

You can bind to `queue.created` Event which will give you the name of the queue in the message header and you can then use it to bind your consumer to that specific queue